# Nightwatch How to use local variable from one function to another

Tags: nightwatch.js, magellan-nightwatch

I want to use local variable pass to another function or compare with any variable. Example:

```
browser
    .waitForElementVisible("//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR uppercase']//strong", 5000, function () {
      browser
      .pause(500)
      .getText("//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR uppercase']//strong", function(result){
        console.log('++++++++++++++',result.value);
        let numb1 = result.value;
        numb = numb1.match(/\d/g);
          numb = numb1.join("");
          console.log("value=", numb1);
          return numb1;
  })
    })

.element('xpath', "(//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR'])[1]", function (present) {
  console.log(present);
  if (present.status == 0) {
    //arrange 
    browser
    .pause(500)
    .getText("(//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR'])[1]", function (result) {
      console.log("string", result.value);
      let numb = result.value;
      numb = numb.match(/\d/g);
      numb = numb.join("");
      console.log("value=", numb);
      return numb;
      })


  }

})
```

I want to compare numb/numb1 or get the total both of them.

Comment: Any news on this? Did you manage to follow the approaches described below? If so, consider [closing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to keep your test structure as is (*pretty suspicious!*), then why don't you declare some test-file global variables?

```
let numb, numb1;

browser
  .waitForElementVisible("//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR uppercase']//strong", 5000, function () {
    browser.pause(500)
      .getText("//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR uppercase']//strong", function(result) {

        numb1 = result.value;
        // > do more stuff here if necessary <
      });
    })
  .element('xpath', "(//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR'])[1]", function (present) {
    console.log(present);

    if (present.status == 0) {
      browser.pause(500)
        .getText("(//div[@class='row']//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR'])[1]", function (result) {

        numb = result.value;
        console.log(`numb & numb1 values: ${numb} & ${numb1}`);
        // > do more stuff with num & numb1 if necessary <
      });
    }
  });
```

***That being said...*** a finer approach would be to break-down your big steps & extract the logic into single-purpose functions, so you would either use:

- [page-object commands](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Page-Object-API);
- or, [custom commands](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/blob/master/examples/custom-commands/hasOnBeforeUnload.js)

Taking into account your current setup, let's consider adding the following **custom command** for extracting your `num1`:

**❒ getNumb1.js** (should reside in `test/custom_commands/`):

```
exports.command = function(callback) {
  this.perform((done) => {
    this.api.waitForElementVisible("//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR uppercase']//strong", 5000, () => {
      this.api.pause(500);
      this.api.getText("//div[@class='col-xs-7 alignR uppercase']//strong", (result) => {
        let numb1 = result.value;
        // > do some other stuff here if necessary <
        callback(numb1);
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Similarly, add a second custom-command file (**getNumb.js**), which will return the value of `numb`. ***Then***, use the two in your test file and do the *data manipulation, or data checking (assertions)* as you please:

```
let numb = browser.getNumb();
let numb1 = browser.getNumb1();

// > do something with numb & numb1 here <
```

> ❖ **!Note:** *The examples given above are purely didactical!* I don't advise
>   creating `custom_commands` containing test-specific logic. Only *general-purpose* and/or *utility methods* (e.g: *closeGDPR*, *addCookie*, *getHttpCode*, etc.) should reside in the `custom_commands` folder.

***Thus,*** in the current setup, it would be best if you would add commands such as `getNumb` & `getNumb1` inside the **commands** section of your page-object.

Comment: Note that there are a couple of issues with this answer.  First, in getNumb1.js the this.api.waitForElementVisible needs to be changed to this.waitForElementVisible.  Also, the suggested commands on how to use this let numb = browser.getNumb(); are throwing an error 'TypeError: callback is not a function'.